# while return rows with a specific value first getting syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want my query to return the rows of the table where a column contains a specific value first

so i given query like this:

```
SELECT IDName
  FROM Type_ofID_tbl
 WHERE deleted = 0
 ORDER BY(IDName ='Emirates ID'), IDName
```

but this showing error

Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: What should this do `order by(IDName ='Emirates ID')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
select IDName 
from Type_ofID_tbl 
where deleted=0 order by case when IDName ='Emirates ID' then 1 else 2 end
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for `(IDName ='Emirates ID')` in the `ORDER BY` clause; it should be like this

```
 SELECT IDName
   FROM Type_ofID_tbl
  WHERE deleted = 0
  ORDER BY IDName ASC
```

If you want to order columns who has the `IDName ='Emirates ID'`

```
 SELECT IDName
   FROM Type_ofID_tbl
  WHERE deleted = 0
    AND IDName = 'Emirates ID'
  ORDER BY IDName ASC
```

The [ORDER BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp) keyword sorts the records in ascending order by default. To sort the records in a descending order, you can use the `DESC` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

SQL table ordering is arbitrary unless explicitly stated. Also you cannot use logical operators in an order by clause.

My advise would be to split this into two queries:

```
SELECT IDNAME FROM [TABLE]
WHERE DELETED = 0
AND IDNAME = 'EMIRATES ID'
UNION ALL
SELECT IDNAME FROM [TABLE]
WHERE DELETED = 0
AND IDNAME != 'EMIRATES ID'
OR IDNAME IS NULL
```

Thanks.